# Can the same trigger work with two different objects

Tags: apex, trigger

Currently I have a Credit_request object.  This object has fields used to report at a high level the required items.  This object has records from an object called Credit_Lines.  I have a trigger that updates the Credit Request based on credit line input.  This functions correctly, however, one gap I noticed is that if I manually change a field in the credit_request object and do not update credit_lines the trigger will not fire.  Is there a way to force the trigger to fire if a field in the credit request section is changed?

```
trigger MakingApprovalRequiredTrigger on Credit_Lines__c (After Insert, After Update, After Delete){

List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id>();

If(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
    For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
        If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
            parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
        }
    }
}


If(Trigger.IsDelete){
    For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.Old){
        If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
            parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
        }
    }
}

List<Credit_Request__c> parentFinalList = New List<Credit_Request__c>();
Double d = 0.00;

For(Credit_Request__c crdReq : [Select Id, Approval_Required__c,Reason_for_request__c,
                                        (Select Id, Quantity__c, Product__c FROM Credit_Lines__r WHERE Product__c = '01t70000004Oxl4AAC' OR Product__c = '01t3900000OMrYrAAL') 
                                                                    FROM Credit_Request__c 
                                                                            WHERE Id =: parentIds])
{
    d = 0.00;
    Set<String> ProductCodes = New Set<String>();

    For(Credit_Lines__c EveryChild : crdReq.Credit_Lines__r )
    {
        d += EveryChild.Quantity__c;
        ProductCodes.add(String.valueOf(EveryChild.Product__c));
    }
     If(crdReq.Reason_for_request__c.Contains('308 CR-Service/Troubleshooting') || crdReq.Reason_for_request__c.Contains('208 PB-Service/Troubleshooting'))

            If(d > 1.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t70000004Oxl4AAC'))
                {
                    crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                }
            else If(d > 1.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t3900000OMrYrAAL'))
                {
                    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                }
            else
                {
                    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );                
                }

    else 
        {
            If(d >= 0.5 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t70000004Oxl4AAC'))
                {
                    crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                }
            else If(d >= 0.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t3900000OMrYrAAL'))
                {
                    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                }
            else
                {
                    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;
                    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );                
                }         
        }        


try
{
    If(!parentFinalList.IsEmpty()){
        update parentFinalList;
    }
}
Catch(Exception e){
    System.debug('Exception Thrown For MakingApprovalRequired Is:: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use (what I call) a blank update to force database rules to run on an object:

```
trigger CreditRequestTrigger on Credit_Request__c(after update)
{
    update [select ID from Credit_Lines__c where Credit_Request__c in :Trigger.New];
}
```

As Derek F pointed out in comments, you should be careful when updating another object in a trigger in general, as you can cause recursion between the two objects if they can update each other.  This is very easy to do with Master-Detail records, since roll-up fields cause an update to the parent, so if you update something in `Credit_Lines__c` which is part of a roll-up field on `Credit_Request__c`, you will end up calling your `Credit_Request__c` trigger again.  You can prevent this using static variables, which will retain their value throughout the entire database transaction.

Comment: One thing to be mindful of when using this (especially when you're in a trigger on a Parent object, and want to update child records) is recursion. If your child object also has code that updates the parent object (or a rollup summary field), you would get yourself into an infinite loop without some recursion control.

Answer (score 4):

No, triggers are object specific, you can see, the first line of code gives the trigger a name, specifies the object on which it operates, and defines the events that cause it to fire:

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (trigger_events) {
   code_block
}
```

If you want, you can vote on an existing [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aM4JAAU) for supporting multiple objects.

Additionally, in the [apex triggers best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) guide, you can read further details details on trigger best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the input, we have limited resources.  To do this coding.  Is there a easy way to covert a trigger into a class.  Updated to include code

Comment: I would suggest creating a new post for this rather than modifying the existing one.

Comment: Created new post Convert a trigger to a class to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a trigger to fire when either object A or Object B is updated, then consider using the new platform events feature:

1. define the event - its like a custom object - you can define whatever fields you want on the event.
2. Create workflow, or a trigger, to create the platform events (workflow off of Object A, and another on Object B)
3. Create a trigger on the event - this trigger will fire whenever the event is created.

Since both Object A and Object B are creating events - the trigger will effectively fire for 2 objects.

Here is a trailhead with some trigger code examples: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/platform_events_basics/units/platform_events_architecture